# How to get my facebook like button to not sink below other social buttons

Tags: css, facebook, button, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button next to stumbleupon and google plus buttons, but the facebook button is beign stubborn and sinks below the other buttons a few pixels extra. Anyone know of a fix for this? (It's the html5 fb button) However, I have tried CSS and even editing the code in the button itself with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```